# ImportError: cannot import name Counter

Tags: python

I have tried using Counter() but everytime I do:

```
from collections import Counter
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<web session>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

Do I actually have to make a file that has counter in it and then import it from there or something?
I am a beginner so only the most basic answer will do.

Answer (score 39):

Counter is only supported python2.7 and higher and is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks, you're the only guy whom answer really the question, it's helps me.

Comment: @sharafjaffri You should probably accept his answer, then, as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
from collections import Counter
```

and be sure that the `C` letter of `Counter` is a capital letter.

Comment: getting down votes because this doesn't answer the question, however this was actually the mistake that I was making so +1 from me!

Comment: Upvote from me too as I made that mistake as well, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast the list to a `set` instead:

```
l = ['a','b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 's', 'd', 'e', 'c']
print (len(set(l)) #prints  6
```

Comment: thanks, it now works except doe one thing. when you have a list of string and one of the strings is an empty string, how do u get rid of it?

Comment: @KeelyAranyos  your_list.remove('')

Answer (score 2):

Rename your file as may your file named as collections or Counter. After that this will works

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you want to use Counter from collections. Counter is used when you want to do something like count the number of occurrences of each word. For example:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(['dog','cat','dog']) # Should output Counter({'dog': 2, 'cat': 1})
```

To count the number of distinct words in a list, you might try using the following:

```
len(set(yourList))
```

of to avoid duplicates with different cases:

```
len(set(word.lower() for word in yourList))
```

A set is allowed to contain only one instance of the items it contains, unlike a list.

You might have an earlier version of Python that doesn't include Counter in the standard library. If that is the case, you should update to a newer version if you can.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python3**

```
import collections
a=collections.Counter(list(i for i in input()))
print(a)
```

input-
`aaabbbcccc`

output-
`Counter({'c': 4, 'a': 3, 'b': 3})`

if you want elements then use `a.elements()` , for getting values use `a.values()`